# Why is the output NaN?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning Javascript, when I want to calculate using a formula the resulting data is NaN.

I want the resulting data to be

```
ar = [37, 36.63, 35.68, 38.81, 37.67, 37.64, 37.64, 39.74, 40.67, 40.61];

ma = [0.00, 0.63, 3.32, 0.81, 0.33, 0.36, 2.36, 1.26, 0.33, 1.61];
```

Is there something wrong with my code that is making me get this answer?

```js
var suhu = [37, 36, 39, 38, 38, 38, 40, 41, 41, 39];

var ar = []
var ma = []
var temp = 0

// AR
for (var i = 1; i < suhu.length; i++) {
  ar[0] = suhu[0]
  temp = 0.99 * suhu[i - 1] + 0.06 * ma[i - 1]
  ar.push(temp)
}

// MA
for (var j = 0; j < suhu.length; j++) {
  suhu[j] = Math.abs(suhu[j] - ar[j]);
  ma.push(suhu[j])
}

console.log(ar);
// 37, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN
console.log(ma);
// 0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN
```

Comment: `ma[i - 1]` will be undefined when the first loop is run. So any math done with undefined becomes `NaN`

Comment: There are no elements in `ma`

Comment: If you multiply by `undefined`, then your result will be Not A Number (NaN)

Comment: I also think like this, because when I change ma[i-1] to 2, the result is not NaN. So what should I do about it?

Comment: Provide `ma` with values? We don't know what your code is supposed to do, so we can't really know what your code should be changed to.

Comment: do you have a wanted result?

Comment: The result i want
.
ar = [37, 36.63, 35.68, 38.81, 37.67, 37.64, 37.64, 39.74, 40.67, 40.61];
ma = [0.00, 0.63, 3.32, 0.81, 0.33, 0.36, 2.36, 1.26, 0.33, 1.61];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the calculation of `ar[i]` depends on `ma[i-1]` and `ma[i]` depends on `ar[i]` so you need to calculate these in the right order in a single loop.

```js
const suhu = [37, 36, 39, 38, 38, 38, 40, 41, 41, 39];
const ar = [];
const ma = [];

// Calucate AR and MA together
ar[0] = suhu[0]
for (var i = 0; i < suhu.length; i++) {

  if (i > 0)
    ar.push(0.99 * suhu[i - 1] + 0.06 * ma[i - 1])

  ma.push(Math.abs(suhu[i] - ar[i]));
}

console.log(ar);
// [37, 36.63, 35.6778, 38.809332, 37.66855992, 37.639886404799995,
//  37.641606815711995, 39.74150359105728, 40.66550978453656, 40.6100694129278]
console.log(ma);
// [0, 0.6300000000000026, 3.3222000000000023, 0.8093319999999977, 0.33144008000000014,
//  0.36011359520000497, 2.358393184288005, 1.2584964089427189, 0.3344902154634397, 1.6100694129277997]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

The results are accurate to more than 2 decimal places and you will need that to calculate the next values correctly. You can change the precision once all the values have been calculated though.

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

> So what should I do about it?

Calculating the values in `ar` and `ma` seems so dependent on each other. *To calculate `ar[i]` you need `ma[i-1]` and for `ma[i]` you need `ar[i]`.* This should be a single loop. You can't first compute one array and then the other.

```js
var suhu = [37, 36, 39, 38, 38, 38, 40, 41, 41, 39];
var ar = [suhu[0]];
var ma = [0];

for (let i = 1; i < suhu.length; ++i) {
  ar[i] = 0.99 * suhu[i - 1] + 0.06 * ma[i - 1];
  ma[i] = Math.abs(suhu[i] - ar[i]);
}

console.log(ar);
console.log(ma);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Answer (score -1):

you havent initialized the ma[] at start and used it for initializing ar[] so it producing Nan value.

Comment: The solution is a bit more involved than that as the values of `ar` and `ma` depend upon each other.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

In JavaScript, NaN stands for Not a Number. It represents a value which is not a valid number. It can be used to check whether a number entered is a valid number or not a number.

From [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-number-nan-property/#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20NaN%20stands%20for,number%20or%20not%20a%20number](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-number-nan-property/#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20NaN%20stands%20for,number%20or%20not%20a%20number).

Comment: Although helpful information, this doesn't really help OP resolve their issue.